# Honda Accord 2008 Overheating at cold start

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, temperature, smoke

I've been having quite a problem with my car. At cold start the temperature goes straight to hot, A/C stops working, car smokes black and this happens at any giving time. I changed the temperature sensor and nothing. Changed the thermostat and nothing. Only thing that I haven't changed is the cooling sensor. Any ideas if there is something else going on with my car?

Tnx in advance guys

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  I assume you've checked your coolant level, since you've changed the thermostat.  If not, that's really important.  Otherwise, you could try just taking out the thermostat to see if that changes anything.  How long does it take for the temperature to go to hot?  If it's almost instant, you probably have an electrical issue.  Also where is the black smoke coming from?  That's not a good sign, but it's worse some places than others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed main Temperature control sensor for fans.most of them bottom of radiator.it controls all fan sensos tells fans through comp to come on off.    It sounds to me from what you described that you loseing water circulation .you changed thermostat ok have you changed water pump.if you have then you have a week head gasket .when it's cold let's heat from piston  seep through.when it's hot block expands head when it's hot expands makes gasket tight and everything goes back to running Right .fix is either water pump .  Not water pump try retorque head bolts .there is no reason other than that that I can think of but one hair line crack in head or leaking head gasket coming from exsaust please forgive my spelling . Check cold start take radiator cap off hold hand over it while it's cold .start vehicle see iff you have pressure under your hand soon as it starts if so bad head gasket or cracked head .start buy checking water pump.cold start with thermostat in it water should be full not moving much take a little Easter egg die just a couple drops see if it moves .thanks for listening been there done that  .go to parts house if it's head gasket get can or bottle of k w block seal drain radiator put it in 3 quarts water put it in radiator start it up says run 20 minutes .trick take thermostat out run  about 3 to 4 hour's or untill motor smothe out .cut off drain.let set for a few hours.hope it helps and you have Good.